# Split-Pipeline parallel jobs script won't finish the last job

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, pipeline, jobs, freeze

So I've been using Split-Pipeline module for some time now, and what bothers me about it, rarely does it really finish. I always get stuck with the last job in the queue hanging and have to either stop the script or kill ISE:

VERBOSE: Split-Pipeline: Jobs = 1; Load = End; Queue = 0

example: 300 servers, running a scan for hotfixes on them using split-pipeline. I'm using pretty standard parameters:

$servers | Split-Pipeline -Verbose -Count 10 { process {#some code for scanning#}}

So 10 jobs each loaded with 30 servers, first lets say 250 servers are scanned really fast, then it slows down a little and when the last job remains only, it never finishes...

Anyone experienced something similar? I've tested the same on several machines and it's always the same so I don't think it's related to the machine running the script.

EDIT: heres the code

```
$servers = (Get-Clipboard).trim() #server1..100
$KB = (Get-Clipboard).trim() -split ', ' #KB4022714, KB4022717, KB4022718, KB4022722, KB4022727, KB4022883, KB4022884, KB4022887, KB4024402, KB4025339, KB4025342, KB4021903, KB4021923, KB4022008, KB4022010, KB4022013, KB3217845

$servers | Split-Pipeline -Verbose -Variable KB -Count 10 { process {
        $hash = [ordered]@{}
        try
        {
            $hash.Hostname = $_
            $os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $_ -ErrorAction Stop
            $hash.OS = $os.Caption
            $hash.Architecture = $os.OSArchitecture
            $today = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($os.LocalDateTime)
            $hash.LastReboot = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($os.LastBootUpTime)
            $hash.DaysSinceReboot = ($today - $hash.LastReboot).Days
        }
        catch
        {
            $hash.OS = $Error[0]
            $hash.Architecture = 'N/A'
            $hash.LastReboot = 'N/A'
            $hash.DaysSinceReboot = 'N/A'
        }

        try
        {
            $hash.PendingReboot = icm -cn $_ {
                if (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -EA SilentlyContinue) { return $true }
                if (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -EA SilentlyContinue) { return $true }
                if (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -Ea SilentlyContinue) { return $true }
                try
                {
                    $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
                    $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
                    if(($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending)
                    {
                        return $true
                    }
                }
                catch{}
                return $false
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            $hash.PendingReboot = 'N/A'
        }

        try
        {
            $hotfix = Get-HotFix -ComputerName $_ -Id $KB -ErrorAction Stop
            if ($hotfix)
            {
                $hash.Hotfix = $hotfix.HotFixID -join ','
            }
            else
            {
                $hash.Hotfix = "No Hotfix from the list applied"
            }        
        }
        catch
        {
            $hash.Hotfix = $Error[0]
        }
        $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash
        $obj | Export-Csv c:\temp\hotfixes.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean this module, have you considered creating an Issue on GitHub? https://github.com/nightroman/SplitPipeline/issues

Comment: Could you post the parallel script . how are you are checking that ? are you doing using runspaces? or jobs ?

Comment: Perhaps `#some code for scanning#` just hangs (~ takes too long) on one of the servers. It's difficult to guess without the actual code.

Comment: added the code, but this issue happens with all sorts of different code, guess ill create an issue on github as proposed

Comment: Does the code work for all servers without using `Split-Pipeline`?

Comment: Related or not, `$obj | Export-Csv c:\temp\hotfixes.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force` is not quite right. You are writing from 10 parallel jobs to the same file.

Comment: the same crossed my mind, I commented the line but it made no difference... and yes, the code works fine without using split-pipeline

Comment: So... The problem is specific to your code, it is not common. Something conflicts with the used parallel pipelines approach. Try to strip (or add) "line-by-line" in order to find the exact culprit. Then avoid this or find a work around. That's all, unfortunately, I can tell. (I am the author, btw. You can submit the bug but the answer will be the same more likely).

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) `Get-HotFix` is not designed for parallel runs. I would try to wrap it by another `icm -cn $_ {...}`

Comment: Yeah it was something weird happening with Get-Hotfix and 1 specific server, which was really running the scan for like 2 hours even without Split-Pipeline... anyway, i am using the module for many other tasks and its been working fine. Wish there were more tools for parallel tasks. Workflow seems quite unstable :/